# ¿el controlador me toma un dato como null pointer exception?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, mvc, rest

tengo un problema, estoy realizando un sistema para salidas de almacen en el cual en una salida salen muchos productos y estoy batallando para que la salida registre todo los productos que salen y la cantidad que salen de cada producto, estoy utilizando java web con modelo mvc y servicios REST,

lo que pasa es que al querer guardar el registro de la salida de un almacén, me marca el error de null pointer exception y lo marca en la parte del controlador en la función del prepareStatement
anexo error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.usae.ssa.controller.ControllerSalidas.insertSalidas(ControllerSalidas.java:102)
> at org.usae.ssa.rest.RESTSalidas.saveSalida(RESTSalidas.java:43)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

este es el json que manda al intentar registrar la salida

```
{
  "producto": [
    {
      "idMobiliario": 1,
      "producto": {
        "idProducto": 3,
        "precio": 550,
        "nombrePro": "Silla para Docente",
        "UM": "PZA",
        "cantidad": 5,
        "descripcion": "Silla de un buen Material",
        "anio": "2022",
        "claveProducto": "MBL01",
        "estatusPro": 1
      },
      "cantidadS": "4"
    },
    {
      "idMobiliario": 3,
      "producto": {
        "idProducto": 17,
        "precio": 450,
        "nombrePro": "Loker ",
        "UM": "PZA",
        "cantidad": 30,
        "descripcion": "Mueble para biblioteca",
        "anio": "2022",
        "claveProducto": "MBL04",
        "estatusPro": 1
      },
      "cantidadS": "3"
    },
    {
      "idMobiliario": 4,
      "producto": {
        "idProducto": 27,
        "precio": 250.9,
        "nombrePro": "Mesabanco",
        "UM": "PZA",
        "cantidad": 25,
        "descripcion": "Mesabanco para alumnos de material de fierro con forro suave en el asiento",
        "anio": "2022",
        "claveProducto": "MBL05",
        "estatusPro": 1
      },
      "cantidadS": "2"
    },
    {
      "idLibrosTexto": 1,
      "nivelEscolar": "Primero de Secundaria",
      "producto": {
        "idProducto": 1,
        "precio": 3500,
        "nombrePro": "Atlas de Mexico",
        "UM": "PZA",
        "cantidad": 550,
        "descripcion": "libro de texto gratuito",
        "anio": "2022",
        "claveProducto": "LBTXT01",
        "estatusPro": 1
      },
      "cantidadS": "5"
    },
    {
      "idLibrosTexto": 4,
      "nivelEscolar": "1ero de Secundaria",
      "producto": {
        "idProducto": 23,
        "precio": 0,
        "nombrePro": "Español",
        "UM": "PZA",
        "cantidad": 631,
        "descripcion": "Libro de español para alumnos de 2do grado de secunadaria",
        "anio": "2022",
        "claveProducto": "LBTXT05",
        "estatusPro": 1
      },
      "cantidadS": "1"
    }
  ],
  "empleado": {
    "idEmpleado": "2"
  },
  "centroDTrabajo": {
    "idCentrosTrabajo": "2"
  },
  "idSalidas": 0,
  "fecha": "2022-07-05",
  "entrega": "javier Sanchez Cruz",
  "recibe": "as"
}
```

como podran observar dentro del objeto de productos y dentro del json de producto a salir ahi va la cantidadS osea esa cantidad es la que marca como null pointer dentro del controlador

anexo codigo de controlador

```
public int insertSalidas(Salida s)throws Exception
    {
        //Definimos la consulta SQL que invoca al stored procedure:
       String sql= "insert into salidas (fecha,entrega,recibe,Empleado_idEmpleado,centrosTrabajo_idcentrosTrabajo)" +
"values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
       
         String sql2="insert into salidas_has_productos (Salidas_idSalidas,Productos_idProductos,cantidadS)" +
"values(?, ?, ?)";
       
       String sql3="update productos inner join Salidas_has_Productos sp on sp.Productos_idProductos=productos.idProductos" +
"set cantidad=cantidad-? where idProductos=?";

       //Aqui gurdaremos los ID's que se generan:
       int idSalidaGenerado=-1;
       int idSalidas_has_ProductosGenerado=-1;
       int cont = 0;
        List<Producto> productos = null;
        List<Salidas_has_Productos> sp=null;
                
        ControllerProducto cp=new ControllerProducto();
      //Con este objeto nos vamos a coonectar a la base de datos:
        ConexionMySQL connMySQL=new ConexionMySQL();
        
        //Abrimos la conexion con la base de datos;
        Connection conn=connMySQL.open();
        PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt2=null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt3=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        try {
            
         
       
        //Con este objeto invocaremos al StoredProcedure:
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        
        //Establecemos los parametros de los datos personales en el orden
        //en que los pide el procedimiento almacenado, comenzando en 1:
        
     
        pstmt.setString(1, s.getFecha());
        pstmt.setString(2, s.getEntrega());
        pstmt.setString(3, s.getRecibe());
        pstmt.setInt(4, s.getCentroDTrabajo().getIdCentrosTrabajo());
        pstmt.setInt(5, s.getEmpleado().getIdEmpleado());
        
       
               
        //Ejecutamos el Stored Procedures:
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        
        //le pedimos al preparedStatement l valor de las claves primarias
        //generadas, que en este caso es solo un valor
        rs=pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        
         rs.next();
         s.setIdSalidas(rs.getInt(1));
            //Cerramos el ResultSet:
            rs.close();
        

        //************ Ejecutamos la Segunda Consulta *********************************************//
       pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            //Salidas_has_Productos sp = null;
       Producto p=new Producto();
       //roductos.add(p.toString());
      
            List<Salidas_has_Productos> salidas_has_productos = null;
            
            salidas_has_productos=s.getSp();
            //System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"+productos);
           // System.out.println("LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL"+salidas_has_productos);
         productos=cp.getAll("");
        for (int i = 0; i < productos.size(); i++) {
                     
            pstmt2.setInt(1, s.getIdSalidas());
            pstmt2.setInt(2,productos.get(i).getIdProducto());
            pstmt2.setInt(3, s.getSp().get(i).getCantidadS());
            pstmt2.addBatch();
        }
        pstmt2.executeBatch();
        
        rs=pstmt2.getGeneratedKeys();
        while (rs.next()){
                s.getSp().get(cont++).setIdSalida_has_Productos(rs.getInt(1));
            
            //Cerramos el ResultSet:
            rs.close();
        }
            
           //*********************************** EJECUTAMOS LA 3ER CONSULTA ******************//
             pstmt3 = conn.prepareStatement(sql3);
            for (int i = 0; i < productos.size(); i++) {
            pstmt3.setInt(1, productos.get(i).getCantidad());
            pstmt3.setInt(2, productos.get(i).getIdProducto());
            
        }
            
            pstmt3.executeUpdate();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            
            throw e;
        }
            
         pstmt.close();
         pstmt2.close();
         pstmt3.close();
         conn.close();
        connMySQL.close();
         rs.close();

        //Devolvemos el Id de empleado generado:
        return s.getIdSalidas();
    }
```

anexo el codigo de javaScript

```
function guardarSalida() {
   
 // Creamos un nuevo objeto
    var salida = new Object();
    //var sp =new Object();
   // salida.sp =new Object();
    salida.producto=new Object();
    salida.empleado = new Object();
    salida.centroDTrabajo = new Object();
   // salida.sp=new Object(); 
 console.log(productosTotales);
    // Agregamos sus propiedades y sus valores:
    salida.idSalidas = 0;
    salida.producto = salidasProductos;
    //salida.producto.idProducto = $('#txtIdProductoS').val();
    salida.empleado.idEmpleado = $('#txtIdEmpleado').val();
    salida.centroDTrabajo.idCentrosTrabajo = $('#txtIdCT').val();
    salida.fecha = $('#datepicker').val();
    salida.entrega=$('#txtNombreE').val();
    salida.recibe=$('#txtRecibe').val();
  

 
    //Revisamos si hay un ID previo
    if($('#txtIdSalida').val().length > 0)
    {
        salida.idSalidas = parseInt($('#txtIdSalida').val());
       
       
    }
   
    $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                async: true,
                url  : "api/salidas/saveSalida",
                data : {salidas : JSON.stringify(salida)}
    })
    .done(function(data){
                //Revisamos si hubo un errror
        if (data.error != null)
        {
            Swal.fire('Error', data.error, 'warning');
        }
        else
        {
            refrescarTablaSalidas(); 
            
            $('#tbl').show();
            salida = data;
            
           // $('#txtIdSalida').val(salida.idSalida);
          // salida.idSalidas = $('#txtIdSalida').val();
           salida=document.getElementById($('#txtIdSalida').val(salida.idSalidas));
            Swal.fire('Movimiento realizado', 'Registro de Salida Guardado Exitosamente.', 'success');
                    limpiarFormulario();
                 //   mostrarDetalleP(salida.idSalida);
        }
            });
}
```

y anexo codigo de el servicio REST

```
@Path("saveSalida")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response saveSalida(@FormParam("salidas") @DefaultValue("{}") String jsonSalida){
        int a =0;
        System.out.println(jsonSalida);
        String out=null;
        ControllerSalidas cs=new ControllerSalidas();
        Salida salidas=null;
        try {
            
                Gson gson=new Gson();
                salidas = gson.fromJson(jsonSalida, Salida.class);
               
                 int r= cs.insertSalidas(salidas);
                
                out = "{\"result\":\"Salida " + r + " generado con éxito\"}";
            
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            out="{\"error\":\"Ocurrio un error inesperado.   Intenta nuevamente o llama al administrador de servicios\"}";
            
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(out).build();
    }
```

espero que puedan ayudarme con mi problema, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

No es que haya un dato nulo. NPE significa que intentas usar una instancia de una clase e invocar un método de ella, siendo que no está inicializada y apunta a NULL.

Por ejemplo, está rarísimo que hagas

```
while (rs.next()){
                s.getSp().get(cont++).setIdSalida_has_Productos(rs.getInt(1));
            
            //Cerramos el ResultSet:
            rs.close();
        }
```

Porque en la primera iteración cierras el resultSet. Qué se supone que hay en `rs` cuando vuelves a ejecutar `rs.next()`?

Comment: se supone que esta la segunda consulta que es la que genera el problema en la parte de pstmt2.setInt(3, s.getSp().get(i).getCantidadS());